# Google Analytic API general issues

Tags: php, api, google-analytics

In trying to follow the Hello Analytics API (https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api) I have found many issues. I have downloaded it off github as described. The problem is: The API comes with errors itself. Firstly it has many internal (files from within the api to other files within the api) link errors. It does not link correctly to its other files. I was able to fix this

But, some functions that the class in the API provides are incorrect as well. There are errors that exist within the php files the api provides. Such as : 
 Call to undefined method Google_Http_Request::getItems(). 
This is due to a incorrect return type

In conclusion the API comes with errors within itself! How has anyone been able to use this API if it causes errors before it can even execute?

Did i download it from the correct location? (https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)

Is there something causing an error with my server?

I dont understand how the API has errors by itself

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
The reason is that the function getItems return bad type in case it fails (http instead of list).